# Loader jquery animation not work on webview android

Tags: android, jquery, css, load, loader

here my css loader to give animation on load every page

```
.loader{position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;
z-index:9999;display:block;
background:url(../../images/loading.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #f9f9f9}
```

my jquery

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

in every browser on dekstop or mobile is work, when im create webView on native andoid apk its always only display image loading.

is there anything to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add this code for run javascript or jquery

```
yourwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

good luck.